# Highlight View parent menu item on node page and rebuild breadcrumb

Tags: 7, views, breadcrumbs, routes

*If you are new to Drupal, as I am, you surely asked yourself once about "How can I highlight parent Views menu item even if I am on a child node? And how can I keep a correct breadcrumb if I use one?"... That's why I wanted to share a little clue in here.*

**My situation:**

I have a content-type named "Testimonial". I created a **View** for my testimonial's nodes, with a **menu item** "Témoignages" in a secondary menu on the left of my page (called "Ressources").

**First problem: the menu**

/!\ This menu **displays only on the pages whose menu item is present** in the menu. For example, "Marchés publics en Wallonie", "Aides publiques en Wallonie", "Témoignages" (= Testimonials), ...

[image]

When I am the the View page, with the list of my testimonial's nodes, the menu item is **highlighted automatically** by Drupal. Nice.

But when I click on a node and access the **full view page**, the "Ressources" menu disappears. This behaviour is normal for all other menu item's children pages. But I want to **make an exception** for the testimonials.

**Second problem: the breadcrumb**

Breadcrumb on Views page:

[image]

Breadcrumb on testimonials node page:

[image]

**My final question:**

How can I keep the menu block in testimonials node pages (only) and make the menu item "Témoignages" **highlighted**? And how can I keep a **correct breadcrumb** in the same time?

Comment: Hi! I don#t have time for a complete answer, but I usually use [Crumbs](https://drupal.org/project/crumbs) + [Menupoly](https://drupal.org/project/menupoly) for this exact problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To **display the** "Ressources" **menu** in a testimonial node page, Drupal **should believe** that we are actually on the "Témoignages" Views page. Plus, it will **highlight** automatically the good menu item.

But, we also need a correct breadcrumb. That's why we have to **save** in a variable the "**true nature of the page**" (a node) before letting know to Drupal that we are on a view.

That's that we do here:

```
function pwe_testimonial_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  // When we are on a Testimonial node page
  if($node->type == "testimonial" && $view_mode == "full") {
    // We save the true nature of the page
    $_SESSION['pwe_testimonial_active_trail'] = serialize(menu_get_active_trail());
    $_GET['pwe_node_id'] = $node->nid;
    // And set the active menu item as "Témoignages"
    menu_set_active_item("testimonial");
  } else {
    // If we are not on a Testimonial node page,
    // we unset the custom variable.
    if(isset($_SESSION['pwe_testimonial_active_trail'])) {
      unset($_SESSION['pwe_testimonial_active_trail']);
    }
  }
}
```

To rebuild the true breadcrumb, we use the variable saved in previous function.

```
function pwe_testimonial_menu_breadcrumb_alter(&$active_trail, $item) {
  if($item && $item['path'] == "testimonial") {
    if($_GET['pwe_node_id']) {
      if(isset($_SESSION['pwe_testimonial_active_trail'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['pwe_testimonial_active_trail']);
      }
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION['pwe_testimonial_active_trail'])) {
      $original_active_trail = unserialize($_SESSION['pwe_testimonial_active_trail']);
      if(is_array($original_active_trail)) {
        $total = count($active_trail);
        $active_trail[$total] = $item;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

*That's all. I hope this little Q&A sharing knowledge will help someone in the future.*